# What's the best way to integrate ML methods from Python into your Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, python, architecture

I'm working on a project and I need to use some reinforcement learning in Python but I'd like to display the results on a webpage using Javascript. Just wondering what the best practices were for the implementation of this idea.

Comment: What is "result"?

Comment: Are you planning to pass inputs from your web page to your trained model and return the output to the web page? If thats the case you need not to complicate stuff. Build a simple flask application. Use html forms , pass ajax to post to localhost and append the returned message.

Comment: The "results" would be the performance of the reinforcement model, I'm trying to display how it's learning probably through graphs and charts.